# Using struct id in swiftui list

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I tried to list a array of struct with swiftUI.

```
import SwiftUI

struct User: Codable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
}

struct MyView: View {
    @State private var users = [User]()

    var body: some View {
        List(users, id: \.id) {    // Type '_' has no member 'id'
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text($0.name)
                    .font(.headline)
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

But the compiler report a error show that User struct has no id property.

Comment: I think it should be `var id: UUID()` and the User struct ought to conform to `Identifiable` as well

Answer (score 2):

It should be like below

```
var body: some View {
    List(users, id: \.id) { user in   // << here !!
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(user.name)           // << due to in different block
                .font(.headline)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

At first adding id property is not enough, User has to conform to  Identifiable

```
struct User: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
}
```

Next is easy to use it as the source of List

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var users = [User]()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(users) {
                Text($0.name)
                    .font(.headline)
            }
            Button(action: {
                let u = User(id: UUID(), name: "Name \(Int.random(in: 0 ..< Int.max))")
                self.users.append(u)
            }) {
                Text("Add User")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

List knows the id property exists, so you don't need to use it in the List constructor.